# Camera movement in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs4

OK so i have a character that moves with the mouse. I need it to stay in the center of the screen(kind of like a platformer game). I can't figure out how to access the camera and move it. (Note: I have tried Vcam and moving all of the other objects but Vcam makes the file slow or something [or so i have heard] and moving the other objects in kind of like cheating [and for my needs is insufficient]) I don't have any code because i don't know where to start. Maybe someone can point me into the right direction.

Thanks,
Thor

Answer (score 1):

One way is to store everyhting in one `DisplayObject` and then move that single object based on the camera movement. Instead of moving the camera, move the main container the opposite direction of the camera.  I'm not sure why you seem to suggest a strategy like this is "cheating" as it is a perfectly suitable way to doing this.

Comment: hmm.. It seems like if i wanted to make a multiplayer game(human players) it would be impractical unless i made a screen the size of the stage...

Comment: Why is that impractical? I'm not sure at all what you are saying about it being different for multiplayers.  If there are two screens, use two `DisplayObjects`

Comment: I think it would be faster to make cameras so that i don't have 20 times that the screen would move for each time that the 20 players move. It seems like it would be glitchy or impractical.

Comment: You wouldn't need to move the screen for each player? You must not understand how to implement this method properly if you think that is how it works.  This method is very practical and can be used quite efficiently without any glitches if it is programmed correctly.

Comment: It wouldn't even be possible to move it to 20 different places, as the map can only be at one place. By the same token, only one player can be in the center. You'd move it relative to whichever player is in the center.

Answer (score 1):

> This is my previous answer on a similar question found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7897879/as3-viewports-without-an-end/7898021#7898021).

What I do here is:

Create a `Map` class with a property `camera` which is another custom class `MapCamera`.

The `MapCamera` has five properties:

1. `_x`
2. `_y`
3. `map` - a reference to the instance of `Map` owning this `MapCamera`
4. `offsetX`
5. `offsetY`

   - The offset values represent the x and y spacing from the left and top edges of the screen, which should be set to half of the stage width and height so that the camera will centre on the stage correctly.
   - The `_x` and `_y` properties are `private`, and have getters and setters.

The getters are pretty basic:

```
public function get x():Number{ return _x; }
public function get y():Number{ return _y; }
```

The setters are where the viewport will be altered, like so:

```
public function set x(n:Number):void
{
    _x = n;
    map.x = -(_x + offsetX);
}

public function set y(n:Number):void
{
    _y = n;
    map.y = -(_y + offsetY);
}
```

From here, you add your children into the `Map` container and then can simply go:

```
map.camera.x = player.x;
map.camera.y = player.y;
```

Which will cause the player to always be in the centre of the screen.

Comment: I am not sure exactly what is going on here. What is n. Maybe can you give a small sample. I haven't been programming in as3 long.

Answer (score 0):

Your camera is only a vector that modifies position of all renderable objects.

```
myMovieClip.x = movingClipPosition.x + camera.x
```

So if the camera.x is moved to the right, this will make the object move the left, giving the impression of a "camera".

Comment: do i access the camera by referencing "camera".

Comment: No, by default no camera exists, you have to create a camera class. This might help furthur, http://www.8bitrocket.com/2008/9/27/Tutorial-N-way-tile-based-blit-fine-scrolling-in-AS3-part-1/